# Deleting all text/mms messages programmatically. but some are leftover

Tags: android

I found two answers on Stackoverflow on how to delete SMS messages programmatically. I'm running this on an app which is set to be the default messaging app.

I have tried these two codes

This one which is supposed to delete everything. It deleted most, but about 4-5 did not get deleted.

```
this.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), null, null);
```

and this one, which removed less then the code above

```
Uri inboxUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
int count = 0;
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(inboxUri , null, null, null, null);
while (c.moveToNext()) {
    try {
        // Delete the SMS
        String pid = c.getString(0); // Get id;
        String uri = "content://sms/" + pid;
        count = context.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(uri),
                null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Any idea why a few messages are not being deleted? Any other way to delete all the SMS/MMS messages on the phone?